# Swift Saving data and crash when I attempt to save another value on to original variable

Tags: xcode, swift

My main issue is one of saving and retrieving data outside of Core Data.

I am looking to save 1 variable with persistent data.

The routine crashes after second button press.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

 super.viewDidLoad()

 var amy="2"
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject((amy), forKey: "ggpass")
}


@IBAction func pass(sender: AnyObject) {

// Retrieve the original Variable

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

     var aname5 = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ggpass"))!  as String
      gpass = (aname5.toInt())!

      gpass=gpass+1

      ///Save Data

      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject((gpass), forKey: "ggpass")


    }
```

Comment: Please don't use quote style as a highlight area; add the details of the crash.

Comment: Where is `gpass` declared?  What line does it crash on?  What does the stack trace say?

Comment: gpass is declared in viewdidload as equalling  0 the weird thing is that it works once then crashes when saving again.

Answer (score 6):

You are creating the `NSUserDefaults` as a string, reading it assuming it's a string, and then writing it back as a number - that won't work. You need to either stick to numbers for your values, or strings. Here's a version sticking to strings - a bit clumsy, but closest to your existing code:

```
@IBAction func pass(sender: AnyObject) {
   var aname5 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ggpass")  as? String
   if let gpass = aname5?.toInt() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("\(gpass+1)", forKey: "ggpass")
   }
}
```

Note that you don't need the `synchronize()` call in iOS8 or Yosemite, see http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/.

Answer (score 1):

Retrive the original value of `amy` by using this code:

```
amy = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("ggpass")
```

Then assign its value to `aname5`.

```
var aname5 = amy
```

Your code now looks like:

```
@IBAction func pass(sender: AnyObject) {

amy = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("ggpass")

 var aname5 = amy

 gpass = (aname5.toInt())!

 gpass++

  ///Save Data

  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject((gpass), forKey: "ggpass")


}
```